# Bootstrap or not bootstrap? What is going wrong here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

OK look the images while reading:

I'm working with this template: https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/modern-business/

There is a top menu and it works while I don't include Bootstrap ('js/bootstrap.js'). (When I do click)

Look the image:

[image]

But when I include the Bootstrap file ('js/bootstrap.js') I get this result (is doesn't works). (When I do click):

[image]

This is the header code (HTML):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Modern Business - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <link href="css/dermaquality.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dermaquality.funciones.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dermaquality.script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dermaquality.validadores_campos.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dermaquality.validadores_formularios.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
```

Comment: what's the relation to php? You tagged as such; why? There's also no HTML in here, just CSS and JS.

Comment: Maybe php developers can help... But I now discover a new thing in this error, I discovered that the problem is in the order I'm including the jQuery, if I include first the bootstrap it works fine. I believed the order wasn't important, and most important is I believed jQuery always be first than bootstrap ?

Comment: Try to include all JS libs before you close your body.

Comment: Inspect element and watch what is happening ,its actualy being called two times , first opens , second closes , because bootstrap js and your template core have dropdowns and probably use same logic and classes ,and its being called two times